# Machine with Nvidia card:Issues with mount command on ubuntu using hostname

Tags: mount

OS: Ubuntu14.04 64 bit I have a strange problem occuring on machines with Nvidia cards running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. the mount command works when using the IPAddress but fails when using the host name

Not-working command :

```
sudo -S mount -t cifs //share.test.com/LAB/Testing/Path1/Path2/Requisite/ -o username=blabla,password=blabla /mnt/src_shar_lnx
```

the error being mount:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //share.test.com/LAB/Testing/Path1/Path2/Requisite/ , missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program) In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

The above command works seamlessly on other machines without Nvidia cards.

Working command :

```
sudo -S mount -t cifs //192.168.200.1/LAB/Testing/Path1/Path2/Requisite/ -o username=blabla,password=blabla /mnt/src_shar_lnx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. installing cifs-utils solved the problem

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the upvoted answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of it instead of posting another answer with "resolved"...  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

he error message mentions:

> missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several
>   filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper
>   program

This is relevant given that you are trying to mount CIFS. The /sbin/mount.cifs needs the package named cifs-utils.

so install the package :

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Comment: Just click the little grey ☑ at the left of this text...